# Compile error. Definition mismatch. void (*)(void *)

Tags: c++

I have a function that takes following argument:

```
int setvalue(void (*)(void *));
```

In order to satisfy parameter: `void (*)(void *)`, I created a function like this:

```
    static void *freeFunction(void *freeAbc)
    {
        AllocAbc *abc = (AllocAbc*) freeAbc; 
        if (abc)
        {
            delete abc;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
```

And I'm trying to use both together as :

```
    AllocAbc *allocAbc = new AllocAbc();
    ...
    void *freeAbc = (void *) allocAbc;
    if (setvalue (freeFunction(freeAbc)) < 0)
    {           
        ...
    }
```

I get an error saying `error: invalid conversion from ‘void*’ to ‘void (*)(void*)’ [-fpermissive]`

What should be changed here (either in freeFunction definition or the way I use both) to make it work.

Thanks.

Comment: What line is the error happening on?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do function pointers in C work?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/840501/how-do-function-pointers-in-c-work)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your function should return `void` not `void *`.

```
static void freeFunction(void *freeAbc)
{
    ...
}
```

The `(*)` indicates that `setvalue`'s parameter is a function pointer. It's not part of that function's return type.

```
(void (*)(void *)
 ^^^^  ^  ^^^^^^
  ||   |    ||
  ||   |    ++ parameter types
  ||   |
  ||   + function pointer
  ||
  ++ return type
```

Also, to call `setvalue` you need to pass the function name without calling it.

```
if (setvalue(freeFunction) < 0)
```

To make it clearer, you may want to add an `&` to indicate that you're not calling the function. `&` is optional when passing function pointers, so this is just a readability thing.

```
if (setvalue(&freeFunction) < 0)
```

Comment: Thanks John for detailed explanation. The code does compile now. But 1 more question. I am actually using freeFunction to free the memory passed in by the *freeAbc. How will the function receive the memory address when we are just specifying if (setvalue(&freeFunction) < 0)?

Comment: `setvalue` will have to pass that value when it calls the function. Perhaps you could add a second parameter to `setvalue` so it accepts both a function pointer and a `void *` data argument, and then it calls the function with that data pointer.

Answer (score 3):

You have two problems:

1. Your `freeFunction` returns `void` instead of `void *`.
2. You are passing the return value of `freeFunction(freeAbc)` into `setValue` instead of a pointer to the function itself.

Answer (score 1):

`freeFunction` returns `void*`, but `setvalue` wants a function that returns `void`. They are clearly not the same type.

Also you're passing the return value of `freeFunction` to `setvalue`, but `setvalue` expects a function pointer.